# Populate array with values from another subarray

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, underscore.js

Lets say I have a json resul like this:

```
{
  "results": [{
      "id": 1, "name": "test1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2, "name": "test2",
      "tags": [{"name": "car"},{ "name": "love"}]
    },
    {
      "id": 3, "name": "test3",
      "tags": [{"name": "car"},{"name": "bike"},{"name": "motorcycle"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to mount a new array only with the unique tags, in this example would be car, love, bike, motorcycle.

Sometimes tags is null or empty...

Would have some way to do this without loops? jquery or underscore would fit this? could be done with pure javascript?

cheers

Comment: How does the second array look like? (the one you want to add to this array)

Comment: @Max08 just with the tag name, [{"name": "love"}, {"name": "bike"}]

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR Added a lodash solution if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked about `underscore`, I will provide you with a `lodash` solution (since lodash has effectively replaced underscore). You can use `lodash` to accomplish this using a functional approach with built in methods, like so:

- _.flatMap() -- grab values inside object by property into a single array and flatten any nested arrays
- _.compact() -- remove any `false`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `undefined`, and `NaN`
- _.map() -- same as above, without flattening (no need to here)
- _.uniq() -- return only unique values

```js
var data = {
  "results": [{
      "id": 1, "name": "test1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2, "name": "test2",
      "tags": [{"name": "car"},{ "name": "love"}]
    },
    {
      "id": 3, "name": "test3",
      "tags": [{"name": "car"},{"name": "bike"},{"name": "motorcycle"}]
    }
  ]
};

var uniq = _.uniq(_.map(_.compact(_.flatMap(data.results, "tags")), "name"));
console.log(uniq);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can chain the statements, rather than nesting them (for readability purposes) using `_.chain()`, like so:

```
var uniq = _
    .chain(data.results)
    .flatMap("tags")
    .compact()
    .map("name")
    .uniq()
    .value();  // [ 'car', 'love', 'bike', 'motorcycle' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const tagSet = new Set (                      // use ES6 set to get rid of duplicates
    obj.results
       .filter(r => r.hasOwnProperty('tags')) // check for tags property
       .map(r => r.tags)                      // extract array of array of tag obj
       .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])     // flatten into array of obj
       .map(flat => flat.name)                // extract name property
);
const uniques = [...tagSet];                  // convert back into array

console.log(uniques); // [ 'car', 'love', 'bike', 'motorcycle' ]
```